# Scraping/parsing from a website

Tags: python, parsing, web, screen-scraping, urllib2

I am following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CMyoQbBq5IE&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDfRO5bQFLcVgvIOIhNUZpZf&feature=share and am having a problem with one of the lines.

Using:

```
import urllib2 from urllib, 
import urlopen, 
import re, 
import cookielib from cookielib, 
import CookieJar
```

Scraping from this site: http://www.huffingtonpost.com/feeds/index.xml

Looking at the source code in my webbrowser, each title is wrapped with the following text:

```
<title><![CDATA[New Pan American Health Organization Report Reveals Stunning Suicide Statistics]]></title>
```

The following code works, but is not the solution I want:

```
        titles = re.findall(r'CDATA(.*?)</title>',sourceCode)
        links = re.findall(r'<link>(.*?)</link>', sourceCode)
```

I want it to find the link header, then ignore the following lines of text until after CDATA. Here is what the tutorial suggests:

```
findall(r'<title>.*?CDATA[(.*?)]><\title>',sourceCode)
```

The [ ]brackets seem to be causing me the problems. They are not in the tutorial code as the site seems to be updated and now they are in the HTML. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!! As simple as possible please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Square brackets are a reserved character in regular expressions and need to be escaped (with backslashes).
This should work:

```
findall(r'<title>.*?CDATA\[(.*?)\]><\title>',sourceCode)
```

Comment: Perfect, this works very well! Thanks!

I can't vote it as an answer until I have a bigger rep. Hopefully others do.

Comment: You should probably be able to add it as the best answer though. (The green checkmark)

Answer (score 2):

Don't use regular expressions for this. Utilize the [`feedparser`](https://pythonhosted.org/feedparser/) library for this functionality. Here is a simple [tutorial](https://wiki.python.org/moin/RssLibraries) on how to utilize it.

First, you need to install `feedparser`

```
pip install feedparser
```

Now, a very simple script will pull all titles of articles on the feed:

```
import feedparser

feed_url = "http://www.huffingtonpost.com/feeds/index.xml"
feed = feedparser.parse(feed_url)

for item in feed['items']:
    print item['title']
```

As of this post, that script outputs this:

```
BP's Damage To The Gulf Of Mexico Has Been Wildly Exaggerated, Says BP Flack In Politico Magazine
6 Reasons Why Dominican Republic Road Trips Are the Best
Halloween Trick or Treat Tips for Parents With Kids of Divorce
I Don't Understand Pumpkin Patches, and Other Confessions a Seasonally-Challenged Mother
What Are You Bringing To The Table When You Serve Dinner?
Once a Soldier, Today a Heartist. The Journey From External Demand to Guidance From Within
This Halloween Let's Take Back the Word Superhero
'A Friend of Mine Got Elected President of the United States'
Train Wreck in Slow Motion (Part V): The Retirement Savings Crisis
10 Brooklyn Jewelry Designers with Their Own Shops
Mexican Government -- Tell Us the Truth -- Where are the Ayotzinapa 43?
Nutty or Naughty?
Kailash Mansarovar: The Ultimate Pilgrimage
Why <em>Scandal</em> Is One of the Most Important Shows Ever for the Gay Rights Movement
Feds Loosen Eligibility For Parent Loan Program
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it seems to be a much simpler way to get the titles out. Is it only for use with RSS feeds?  I wanted to use simple expressions as i usually work with text files and other sources etc and hope to move what i learn there.

Comment: The feedparser library is for RSS feeds. There are other libraries available for different tasks

Comment: Thanks for the quick help! I will look at feedparser to see what else I can do with it while i am looking into scraping RSS feeds.